# Using XPath to find rows where a specific column has value

Tags: xpath

I'm having trouble using XPath to find a row in a table where a specific column contains a value. The table has 10 columns where 2 of them will show Yes|No but I'm only interested in finding the value in one of the columns (the 4th one). My initial attempt was this:

```
//table[@id='myTable']/tbody/tr/td[text() = 'Yes']
```

but it finds it rows from both columns. I thought I could try something like this but it's not a valid expression:

```
//table[@id='myTable']/tbody/tr/td[4]/text()='Yes'
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
//table[@id='myTable']/tbody/tr[td[4][. = 'Yes']]
```

The XPath return row (`tr`) having the forth `td` child value equals `"Yes"`.

Comment: @har07...thank you!  this article that I have been looking for for the past 2 weeks!  :)